# Combobox Change, AfterUpdate, and BeforeUpdate Events in Word VBA

Tags: vba, events, combobox, ms-word

What is the difference between Change, AfterUpdate, and BeforeUpdate events for Combobox in Word VBA?

I'm having difficulties in finding documentation for control events in Word VBA (I only found documentation for Access VBA and VB.NET, I don't know if they behave in the same way)

Answer (score 1):

This information is in the Language Reference for MS Forms ("User forms") for Office VBA, rather than in the Help for individual Office applications, which is why you may have had difficulty finding it. For example: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264307.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264215.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264715.aspx